# the implicit derivative of $x+2y+1=\frac{y^2}{x-1}$ at the point $(2,-1)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

So as the title states, I have to find the points $(2,-1)$ for the equation $x+2y+1=\frac{y^2}{x-1}$.

first I multiply both side with $(x-1)$ since when taking the derivative I try to avoid fractions:

I get $(x-1)(x+2y+1)=y^2$.

distributing the equation I get:

$x^2-x+2yx-2y+x-1=y^2$.

So after taking the implicit derivative(not sure of the nomenclature of this kind)

I get:

$2x+2(y'x+y)-2y'-0=2yy'$.

after substituting x and y with (2,-1)

I get $y'=-\frac{3}{2}$

It's supposed to be $y'=-\frac{1}{2}$

I know there are different approaches, like using the quotient rule instead.
However, this should also be a valid approach.

So I would appriciate if somebody could employ my approach, because it discourages me a little when this does't work as I'd wished it to work:)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: When you implicitly differentiate, you only get $2y^{'}$ on the left I don't see how you got $2yy^{'}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative with respect to $x$ of $2y$ is $2y'$ not $2yy'$.

Comment: You're right. But still after the change I get the wrong answer.

Comment: I don't!  I can only suggest you do your arithmetic more carefully.

Comment: I seemed to be somewhat absent-minded. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Given $x+2y+1=\frac{y^2}{x-1}$, we implicitly assume (thus the name) that $y$ is a differentiable function of $x$. Then since the left and right hand sides are two ways of writing the same function, we can differentiate each of them and get another equality (the derivative of the same function). We can differentiate $y$ as simply $y'$ - since we assumed $y$ is differentiable - and for any function $f$, we can differentiate $f(y)$ as $f'(y)y'$, using the chain rule.

So,

\begin{eqnarray}
x+2y+1 &=& \frac{y^2}{x-1} \newline
1 + 2y' &=&\frac{(2y\cdot y')(x-1) - y^2}{(x-1)^2} \newline
 2y' - \frac{2y\cdot y'}{x-1}&=& \frac{-y^2}{(x-1)^2} - 1 \newline
 \left(2 - \frac{2y}{x-1}\right)y' &=& \frac{-y^2}{(x-1)^2} - 1 \newline
y' &=& \frac{\left(\frac{-y^2}{(x-1)^2} - 1\right)}{\left(2 - \frac{2y}{x-1}\right)}
\end{eqnarray}

where the first step is the differentiation and the rest is algebra. You can check that this indeed gives the answer $y' = -1/2$ when $x = 2, y = -1$.

Answer (score 0):

On the left side, the derivative of $x^2-x$ is $2x-1$, not $2x$.